# Flutter FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder gives RangeError Value not in range: 3 error in flutter Web but works well in app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

This is the code for querying user ratings/ reviews from firestore. It works well in the app which is on playstore but gives error in flutter web. any solution cos no further error is shown in the the terminal except range error.

```
Future<void> getReview(String productId) async {
     final QuerySnapshot snapProducts = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('products')
      .doc(productId)
      .collection('reviews')
      .get();
       return snapProducts;
     }

FutureBuilder(
  future: getReview(widget.products.id),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.hasData) {
    final documents = snapshot.data.docs;
     final sum = documents.isEmpty
      ? 0.0
   : documents
      .map((m) => m['rating'])
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b) /
         documents.length;
        return Text(
           '$sum'.substring(0, 3),
           style: TextStyle(
           color: themeChange.isDarkTheme
                  ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
           ),
         ),                
     }
      return const Center(child: Text('...'));
      },
    ),
```

Comment: I think the error is in this line: '$sum'.substring(0, 3),
have you checked that if the sum value is not null?. print(sum) and see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `substring(0, 3)` from your code. It's an int, ,and unless it's more than 9999 it'll keep throwing this error.

Comment: Surprisingly its working. Thanks.. I added substring(0, 3) because I only wanted 1 decimal place after the rating calculation.

Comment: In that case use the asStringFixed(1) method